# Hazelcast Jet - fault tolerance in processing Redis streams

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I have a 3 node `Hazelcast Jet` cluster deployed with few jobs that reads and write to `Redis Streams`.

As of now the streams from `Redis` can either be read from a specific position or from the beggining or the newer ones. If a job got restarted for some reason (bug) it should have to start where it left.

Also, how do I code or configure my jobs in a way it can reattempt to process failed messages, say some runtime exception happend during processing, disconnected network to other webservice, or to Redis cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Jet jobs for fault tolerance via `JobConfig`

```java
JobConfig config = new JobConfig();
config.setProcessingGuarantee(EXACTLY_ONCE)
    .setSnapshotIntervalMillis(3000);
Job job = instance.newJob(p, config);
```

This configures the job so that it takes snapshots every 3 seconds. If your job is restarted, this can happen due to down-scaling/up-scaling of Jet cluster or a manual call `job.restart()`, the source will continue from the last saved snapshot. Some of the messages can be emitted twice, the sink should handle that duplication.

We use `lettuce` client for `RedisSource` and you can configure the timeout via `RedisUri`, lettuce client will try to reconnect in case of a disconnection. But any failure during processing fill fail the job.